# Nested values from same table

Tags: sql

Need to retrieve values from same table where values from one column are used as parent id in different record. This is done on third level meaning that value from first column in one record is used in another record in the second column and then the first column value from the second record is used in yet another records second column. For this third level nesting I've used following query:

```
SELECT C1.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "First", 
       C2.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "Second",
       C3.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "Third" 
FROM CALLCAT C1
JOIN CALLCAT C2
ON C1.CALLCATEGORY = C2.parent_id
JOIN CALLCAT C3
ON C2.CALLCATEGORY = C3.PARENT_ID
WHERE C3.ACTIVE = 1
```

where CALLCATEGORY is first column and PARENT_ID is second column.

This query works fine and I get the result for third level nesting., but I need to find as well records that are nested only on second level and also records that are not nested (their callcategory value is not used as parent_id). 
Basically I need to more queries for second level nesting and no nesting that will have NULL values for the third output column and NULL for second and third column in case of no nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `Union` :

```
SELECT C1.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "First", 
       C2.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "Second",
       C3.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "Third" 
FROM CALLCAT C1
JOIN CALLCAT C2
ON C1.CALLCATEGORY = C2.parent_id
JOIN CALLCAT C3
ON C2.CALLCATEGORY = C3.PARENT_ID
WHERE C3.ACTIVE = 1

UNION

SELECT C1.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "First", 
       C2.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "Second",
       null AS "Third" 
FROM CALLCAT C1
JOIN CALLCAT C2
ON C1.CALLCATEGORY = C2.parent_id
WHERE C2.ACTIVE = 1 and not exists 
(select 1 from callcat where parent_id = C2.CALLCATEGORY)

UNION

SELECT C1.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "First", 
       null AS "Second",
       null AS "Third" 
FROM CALLCAT C1
WHERE C1.ACTIVE = 1 and not exists 
(select 1 from callcat where parent_id = C1.CALLCATEGORY)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this query does the trick. I cam to the same query just did not use the *Select 1* that actually makes it work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try left join

```
SELECT C1.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "First", 
   C2.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "Second",
   C3.CALLCATEGORYDESCR AS "Third" 
FROM CALLCAT C1
LEFT JOIN CALLCAT C2
ON C1.CALLCATEGORY = C2.parent_id
LEFT JOIN CALLCAT C3
ON C2.CALLCATEGORY = C3.PARENT_ID
WHERE C3.ACTIVE = 1
```

Comment: This one only return third level nested values  like 

First Second Third
Value Value Value

While i need a query  that will show as well second level and ne nesting like 

First  Second Third
1. Value  Value NULL
2. Value  NULL NULL
Meaning that record one is used as parent id for the value in Second column, but that record is not nested and its not used as parent id anywhere (therefore NULL as value for Third). 
While for second record, that one is not used as parent id anywhere and its has NULL for both Second and Third Column